# Телграмм бот дропает ошибку

Tags: python, telebot

Написал телеграмм бота через telebot, все хорошо работает, но через время выдает ошибку requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=25)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте заменить `bot.polling()` на:

```
bot.infinity_polling(timeout=10, long_polling_timeout = 5)
```